# SUMIF in multiple sheets without using INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is simplified EXCEL file I am working on.
Data sheet 1 called *first*:

[image]

Data sheet 2 called *second*:

[image]

Data structure and range (`C2:E8`) is same. I need to sum those sheets based on criteria in column B (Option).

Outcome I expect:
*option1_sum* sheet:

[image]

*option2_sum* sheet:

[image]

Tables to test on:

Sheet *first*:

| ID | Option | Result 1 | Result 2 | Result 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 30 | 30 | 30 |
| 4 | 2 | 40 | 40 | 40 |
| 5 | 2 | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| 6 | 1 | 60 | 60 | 60 |
| 7 | 1 | 70 | 70 | 70 |

Sheet *second*:

| ID | Option | Result 1 | Result 2 | Result 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| 3 | 1 | 300 | 300 | 300 |
| 4 | 2 | 400 | 400 | 400 |
| 5 | 1 | 500 | 500 | 500 |
| 6 | 1 | 600 | 600 | 600 |
| 7 | 1 | 700 | 700 | 700 |

I can achieve this by putting either this formula in sum sheet `C2` and dragging to `E8`:

`=SUMIF(first!$B2,$B$2,first!C2)+SUMIF(second!$B2,$B$2,second!C2)`

or this:

`=IF(first!$B2=$B$2,first!C2,0)+IF(second!$B$2=$B2,second!C2,0)`

These works as expected. Calculations are fast. The problem is that in original file there are ~100 data sheets to sum and area is more than 30000 cells in each sheet.
Formulas are getting very long and file is getting too heavy, takes ages to open.

If there wouldn't be `IF` condition I would calculate like this:

`=sum(first:second!C2)`

I expected `SUMIF` to work like this:

`=SUMIF(first:second!$B2,$B$2,first:second!C2)`

Unfortunately it doesn't. Every solution I've found uses `INDIRECT` formula like this:
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Sheetlist&"'!B2"),$B$2,INDIRECT("'"&Sheetlist&"'!C2")))` where Sheetlist is named list:

[image]

It does work, it is much shorter and makes file lighter more than 3 times, but because `INDIRECT` is volatile formula, it freezes excel for 5 seconds every time change is made in data sheets. And changes are made often.

Are there any other ways to make file lighter without losing speed?

Limitations:

- Can't use VBA because it is stored in Sharepoint and accessed via both Excel 365 and browser Excel
- Can't use manual recalculation as it is constantly monitored by several people and changes need to be seen on the spot

UPDATE: @JvdV suggested formula works, but after adding 10+ sheets every recalculations takes more than 5 seconds.

Updated said formula to include blank cells:

```
=LET(x,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(first:last!A1:E8,0),5),IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(0,A2:A8,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,BYCOL(FILTER(DROP(x,,2),(TAKE(x,,1)=b)*(INDEX(x,,2)=B2),0),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c)))))),1),0))
```

Comment: Why not using SUMPRODUCT ?

Comment: @iDevlop somehow I've missed on that. Brilliant! Posted an answer based on your suggestion. Feel free to comment if you see more room for improvement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @iDevlop suggestion to use `SUMPRODUCT` I came to this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TOCOL(first:second!C2),N(TOCOL(first:second!$B2)=$B2))
```

In `C2`, dragged down and right.

Result:

[image]

Speed and overall performance yet to be tested, but at first sight it looks very promising. More important file size was reduced **4 times** (in original work) compared to `SUMIF` formula presented in original post.

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom function from the name manager comes to mind. Something like `=TOCOL(GET.WORKBOOK(1))` would spill all sheetnames but it requires to save your workbook as `.xlsm`. So I came up with another idea. If your sheets are always in order you could do something like:

```
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(first:last!A:E,1),5)
```

Now let's incorporate this into a `REDUCE()` to fill all cells in each sum-sheet:

[image]
[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=LET(x,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(first:last!A:E,1),5),IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(0,A2:A8,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,BYCOL(FILTER(DROP(x,,2),(TAKE(x,,1)=b)*(INDEX(x,,2)=B2),0),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c)))))),1),0))
```

Note that 'last' is just a placeholder for whatever is the last sheet in the sequence of sheets to sum from. I hope that below visual will help cover the basics of the theory implemented:

[image]

Comment: Not trying to piggyback on OP's question but when you're dealing with something like this, do you work form the inside out or construct around your original need? Your last two answers I've seen were similar and I'm trying to understand/learn what they do and was just wondering how you come to this.

Comment: @Notus_Panda, a hard question to answer. I think I do unnoticed start with the essence of the question. What is OP actually trying to do here (in this case a non-volatile reference to multiple sheets without VBA). Once I got that covered I'd try to incorporate it in a bigger formula to spill results. I know it's a somewhat loose idea but it is rather hard to answer =)

Comment: @JvdV thank you! Very interesting approach. Can't wait to adapt it (though do not understand every part yet) to my original file and test speed/file size. Will let you know!

Comment: It looks like I forgot to show what it seems to be a critical detail. It is not only possible, but there always are blank cells in data sheets. For example if I delete value in first!D3, formula breaks. It is expected to treat blank as 0. Blank + blank = 0, blank + 5 = 5. Is it possible to modify it to work with blank cells?

Comment: Expected changing parameter 1 in TOCOL(first:last!A:E,1) to 0 (keep all values) would work, but in this case it stops spilling values at all

Comment: Took me a while - range A:E has "a lot of" blanks, TOCOL(first:second!A1:E8,0) now works with blanks

Comment: @user11222393 or just leave the 2nd parameter. But yes, I just made it work for the entire column. If you need these ranges then kudos to you for editing the solution accordingly!

Comment: Adapted formula to my original work. It works, but after adding 10 sheets it takes more than 5 seconds to recalculate after any change made in datasheets. But thank you, it gave me a lot of ideas on improving formulas on other calculations

Comment: @user11222393, that's still relatively fast. Imagine 10 sheets, taking all cells from A:E and process all these rows....