# How do I autosum cell contents across sheets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I write an excel formula that adds the contents of cell F7 for worksheets labeled 1 through 99 but using the IF statement, if cell C2 for any given worksheet equals 1?

Using ChatGPT, the formula below was given, but it returned an error in excel, whether or not I entered the formula as an array or just hitting enter.

```
=SUM(IF('1:99'!C2=1, '1:99'!C2, 0))
```

Thank you.

I've tried generating a response using suggestions from other discussion forums and using ChatGPT, but there are always minor errors that occur.

Comment: well, try sumif() or sumifs(). did you test the sum without the if()?

Comment: Try: `=SUM(--(TOCOL('1:99'!C2)=1)*TOCOL('1:99'!F7))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SUMIF in multiple sheets without using INDIRECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74823024/sumif-in-multiple-sheets-without-using-indirect)

Comment: Thank you! This worked :)
=SUM(--(TOCOL('1:99'!C2)=1)*TOCOL('1:99'!F7))

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> with <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd> :

```
=SUM(--(TOCOL('1:99'!C2)=1)*TOCOL('1:99'!F7))
```

---

So here in the screenshots showing there are <kbd>99</kbd> Sheets in the same workbook, some are hidden, one of the sheet named <kbd>98</kbd> where the cell <kbd>C2<>1</kbd> while all other sheets have <kbd>C2=1</kbd> hence the total will be <kbd>196</kbd> as <kbd>F7=2</kbd>, output shown using the above formula.

[image]

---

Comment: Nice one! Where were you almost a year ago!

Comment: @user11222393 this was shared 3 months back **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76538347/8162520)**

Comment: In this case I've reinvented the wheel. I wish I had seen this earlier!